# Lambda expressions in C# with If\Else

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010, lambda

I built an SQL Query that order table by complex Condition.
here is a example with the same principle:  (Table Toto include 3 cols: id ,num1,num2)

```
select  t.id 
from Toto as t
group by t.id
order by sum(case when t.id<100 Then t.num1 ELSE t.num2 END)
```

and my question is, there is option to write this query in Lambda?(using when\else)

thank you!

Comment: Think you are missing the point of lamba's, personally. What provider are you using?

Comment: maybe a Linq syntax would be better, like `from t in dbToto groupby ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would look something like this:

```
db.Toto 
  .GroupBy(t => t.id)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Sum(t => t.id<100 ? t.num1 : t.num2)
  .Select(g => g.Key)  // since you're grouping by Id
```

it's the cleaner equivalent of:

```
db.Toto 
  .GroupBy(t => t.id)
  .OrderBy(g => g.Sum(t => {
                              if (t.id<100)
                                  return t.num1; 
                              else
                                  return t.num2;
                           }
                      )
  .Select(g => g.Key)  // since you're grouping by Id
```